# What are the benefits of Lollipop? [Features]

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

The last thing I want to do is fade out of current times & technology.

**So the question:** what will I gain, feature-wise, from upgrading to a phone with Lollipop OS? Put *speed* and *Material theme* aside. What neat little features did they pack into the OS? For example, in 4.3 it was App-ops. Jelly Bean introduced device encryption, screenshots, music EQ, NFC, boot-to-safe-mode, settings shortcuts, lockscreen owner info, you get it. **All the little things we now take for granted.**

So, what's the list for Lollipop? I can think of a couple things, but I had to dig deep. Built-in flashlight is an example. But as far as functionality goes, I couldn't find anything that I can't already do on JB.

Enlighten me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lockscreen and notifications are easily the most dramatic change. 
Notifications on the lockscreen are more powerful. You're able to read and clear notifications without unlocking the phone. Double tapping a notification will bring you directly into an app.

Quicksettings are available from the lockscreen. A 2 finger swipe down from the top in the lockscreen (as well as from any screen in the OS) will reveal quicksettings. You can make limited changes, such as turning on and off wifi, without unlocking the phone.

Smart lock is a number of security settings that allow your phone to automatically unlocked in different situations, depending on location or proximity to another device such as a smart watch or bluetooth keyboard. Face unlock has been folded into Smart Lock. They also added a setting called on-body detection that does pretty much what it sounds like. The main draw to these types of features is to cut down on the times you have to punch in your passcode, even when you are in a secure place.

Another security feature is the ability to put your device in a kind of kiosk mode. Lollipop calls it pinning apps and it basically allows you to lock the phone into a single app so that another user can use that app, but you won't have to worry about them snooping around elsewhere. Phones also now have support for multiple accounts, though that was available previously on tablets.

Recent Apps feature has been redesigned. In addition to the Rolodex-like animation, you can now have it split up your chrome tabs into separate tasks. This has been controversial, but can be turned off.

Answer (score 1):

- Multiple accounts support
- Ability to hide sensitive notifications from the lock screen
- Search in Settings
- Battery saving mode (that can be turned on automatically when the battery is low)